# React hook error when using Material-UI styles

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I've been teaching myself React and node.js in my free time, and am hitting a wall with why my use of material-ui's makeStyles is breaking react hook rules.

I've been replicating the code from the material-ui website but even this appears to break the rules. The key difference between their code examples and mine is that my code has multiple exports. Included code below shows just one of these functions - they would all be very similar in function.

The expected behaviour is that the colour of the Icon changes to a non-OOTB color provided by material-UI.

Instead I get Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. I believe I'm doing this at the top level and not inside of a condition/comparison statement. A bit lost!

Any guidance on where I'm going wrong would be amazing.

Thanks!

```
// ItemHelper.js

import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import AssignmentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Assignment';
import BugIcon from '@material-ui/icons/BugReport';
import BookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Book';
import Help from '@material-ui/icons/Help';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    successIcon: {
        color: 'green'
    },
    errorIcon: {
        color: 'red'
    }
  }));



export function GetIconForItemType(itemTypeID) {

    const classes = useStyles();
    var data = null;

    switch (itemTypeID) {
        case 1:
            data = <AssignmentIcon className={classes.successIcon} />;
            break;
        case 2:
            data = <BugIcon color="error" />;
            break;
        case 3:
            data = <BookIcon color="primary" />;
            break;
        default: 
            data = <Help />;
            break;
    }
    return data;
}
```